# Sending messages to ActiveMQ Artemis not working with SSL enabled property

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

I have 3 pair master/slave Artemis HA cluster setup with replication. They are running on 6 different machines and each of them using their own self signed certificate where `CN` matches the hostname where the brokers are running. It was new in artemis 2.18.0.

`broker.xml` and `bootstrap.xml` with sslEnabled settings looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>amq1</name>
      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>
      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>
      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      <journal-buffer-timeout>28000</journal-buffer-timeout>
      <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>
      <max-disk-usage>100</max-disk-usage>
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
      <critical-analyzer-timeout>150000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
      <page-sync-timeout>1628000</page-sync-timeout>
      <global-max-size>204Mb</global-max-size>

      <connectors>
        <connector name="amq1">tcp://amq1:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/home/vagrant/artemis_certs/client_ts.p12;trustStorePassword=0etjq234NCTgBxP8dc4</connector>
        <connector name="amq2">tcp://amq2:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/home/vagrant/artemis_certs/client_ts.p12;trustStorePassword=0etjq234NCTgBxP8dc4</connector>
        <connector name="amq33">tcp://amq33:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/home/vagrant/artemis_certs/client_ts.p12;trustStorePassword=0etjq234NCTgBxP8dc4</connector>
        <connector name="amq44">tcp://amq44:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/home/vagrant/artemis_certs/client_ts.p12;trustStorePassword=0etjq234NCTgBxP8dc4</connector>
        <connector name="amq5">tcp://amq5:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/home/vagrant/artemis_certs/client_ts.p12;trustStorePassword=0etjq234NCTgBxP8dc4</connector>
        <connector name="amq6">tcp://amq6:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/home/vagrant/artemis_certs/client_ts.p12;trustStorePassword=0etjq234NCTgBxP8dc4</connector>
      </connectors>
       <acceptors>
           <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://0.0.0.0:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://0.0.0.0:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
           <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://0.0.0.0:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>
       </acceptors>
       <broadcast-groups>
           <broadcast-group name="artemis-broadcast-group">
               <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
               <group-port>9876</group-port>
               <broadcast-period>2000</broadcast-period>
               <connector-ref>amq1</connector-ref>
           </broadcast-group>
       </broadcast-groups>
       <discovery-groups>
           <discovery-group name="artemis-discovery-group">
               <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
               <group-port>9876</group-port>
               <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
           </discovery-group>
       </discovery-groups>
      <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
      <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>
      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="artemis-cluster">
            <connector-ref>amq1</connector-ref>
            <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
            <retry-interval-multiplier>3</retry-interval-multiplier>
            <max-retry-interval>5000</max-retry-interval>
            <initial-connect-attempts>-1</initial-connect-attempts>
            <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
            <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
            <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
            <max-hops>1</max-hops>
             <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="artemis-discovery-group"/>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>

      <ha-policy>
        <replication>
          <master>
            <group-name>artemis-group-1</group-name>
            <quorum-vote-wait>12</quorum-vote-wait>
            <vote-on-replication-failure>true</vote-on-replication-failure>
            <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
          </master>
        </replication>
      </ha-policy>

      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>
      <addresses>
         <address name="exampleQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="exampleQueue"/>
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="DLQ">
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>
      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <auto-create-dead-letter-resources>true</auto-create-dead-letter-resources>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <address-setting match="exampleQueue">            
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>                      
            <redelivery-delay>1000</redelivery-delay>    
            <max-delivery-attempts>3</max-delivery-attempts>
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <page-size-bytes>1048576</page-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        </address-setting>
      </address-settings>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

bootstrap.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.org/schema">

   <jaas-security domain="activemq"/>

   <server configuration="file:/home/vagrant/artemis-broker/etc//broker.xml"/>
   <web bind="https://0.0.0.0:8161" path="web" keyStorePath="/home/vagrant/artemis_certs/broker_ks.p12" keyStorePassword="Hf316S2m34234VPuhmv9x" trustStorePath="/home/vagrant/artemis_certs/client_ts.p12" trustStorePassword="0etjq234NCTgBxP8dc4">
      <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
      <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
      <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
   </web>
</broker>
```

Now I'm trying to send messages to the queue from one client machine which is using also the certificate from one of the artemis broker client.

I configured brokerURL with list of all 6 artemis brokers and sslEnabled property but it doesn't not work when I'm trying to execute it.

```java
    @Bean
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory jmsFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                "(tcp://amq1:61616,tcp://amq2:61616,tcp://amq33:61616,tcp://amq44:61616,tcp://amq5:61616,tcp://amq6:61616)?ha=true&sslEnabled=true&trustStorePath=/home/vagrant/artemis_certs/client_ts.p12&trustStorePassword=password");
        factory.setRetryInterval(1000);
        factory.setRetryIntervalMultiplier(1.0);
        factory.setReconnectAttempts(-1);
        factory.setConfirmationWindowSize(10);
        return factory;
    }
```

If I use only property `verifyHost=false` in broker url then it works fine. the URL looks like this:

```xml
(tcp://amq1:61616,tcp://amq2:61616,tcp://amq33:61616,tcp://amq44:61616,tcp://amq5:61616,tcp://amq6:61616)?ha=true&verifyHost=false
```

I would like to make it work also with sslEnabled property but getting this error:

```
Started SpringJmsProducerApplication in 1.476 seconds (JVM running for 1.867)
Sending message 0 @ 2021-10-13 09:32:02.379
2021-10-13 09:32:13.236 ERROR 13894 --- [           main] org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client  : AMQ214016: Failed to create netty connection

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$5.run(SslHandler.java:2003) ~[netty-handler-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:127) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:416) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:331) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.39.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) ~[artemis-commons-2.6.4.jar!/:2.6.4]
```

I added acceptor with sslEnabled in broker.xml file

```xml
      <acceptors>
        <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://amq1:61616?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/home/vagrant/artemis_certs/broker_ks.p12;keyStorePassword=password</acceptor>
      </acceptors>
```

but now I'm getting this error:

```
Sending message 0 @ 2021-10-13 11:23:50.816
Failed: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure (or add) your acceptor with sslEnabled and the keystore/truststore to use.

Comment: could you please also provide an example how it will look like based on my broker.xml config ?

Comment: I updated my post with acceptor configuration but still getting error